# sum of NA's for specific values of columns in df in list

Tags: r

I need to get the sum of NA's per month in a list of data frames.
The list consists of a number of data frames varying in length looking like this:

```
                 date year month day hour rain temp rhum
1 1950-01-01 01:00:00 1950     1   1    1    0  5.1   93
2 1950-01-01 02:00:00 1950     1   1    2    0  6.1   91
3 1950-01-01 03:00:00 1950     1   1    3    0  6.0   92
4 1950-01-01 04:00:00 1950     1   1    4    0  6.1   92
5 1950-01-01 05:00:00 1950     1   1    5    0  6.6   92
6 1950-01-01 06:00:00 1950     1   1    6    0  7.2   92
```

And the output should be the same list of same number of data frames with summary rows for each variable:

```
   year month  rain temp rhum
1  1950     1     2    3    1
2  1950     1     0    0    3
```

This piece of code gives me sums per column per df:

```
lapply(all_st, function(x) sapply(x, function(z) sum(is.na(z))))
```

Comment: Maybe `lapply(all_st, function(x) aggregate(rain + temp + rhum ~ year + month,x, function(z) sum(is.na(z))))`, but it's hard to say without a reproducible example.

Comment: your code got me the format that I wanted, but sums are all zero's. I did not get I am trying to get a reproducible example, but not really sure how to do it with such a large object.

Comment: Are you sure there are `NA`s in your data? In the example you posted there aren't.

Comment: the code I posted gives me a thousands of NA's in some df's. this is only six rows, what I have is hourly weather data from 1950s till now for a number of stations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `data.table`.  Convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(x)`) after looping through the list of data.frames , grouped by 'year', 'month', specify the columns of interest in `.SDcols`, loop through those columns and get the `sum` of the logical vector for NA elements

```
library(data.table)
lapply(all_st, function(x) setDT(x)[, lapply(.SD, function(x) sum(is.na(x))), 
                           by = .(year, month), .SDcols = rain:rhum])
```

Comment: thanks, I found a plyr solution but this work as well.